# bsearch with an array of structs

Tags: arrays, c, struct, binary-search, bsearch

I have an array of structs that has already been sorted using `qsort`. I'm trying to search for a name in struct however it is always returning `NULL`. What is the explanation for why this is happening?

Here is my code:

```
#include "card.h"
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmpname (const void *pa, const void *pb) {
    const char *p1 = pa;
    const index_t * const *p2 = pb;
    //printf("Comparing: %s %s\n", p1, (char*)*p2);
        return strcmp((p1), (*p2)->name);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    unsigned length;
    int i = 0;
    int length_multiplier = 0;
    char *input = NULL;
    char *pItem;
    index_t **indexs = NULL;
    FILE *input_file;
    
    if((input_file = fopen("index.bin", "rb")) != NULL)
    {
        
        // GETS USER INPUT
        printf(">> ");
        size_t num_read = 0;

        getline(&input, &num_read, stdin); 
        printf("Searching for: %s\n", input);
        if(*input != 113)
        {
            // READING FILE AND ADDING ENTRIES INTO STRUCT
            //int *key;
            //int *pItem;
            //input_file = fopen("index.bin", "rb");
            if (input_file == NULL)
            {
                printf("ERROR OPENING FILE\n");
                free(indexs);
                fclose(input_file);
                return 1;
            }
            // READS THE INPUT FILE
            for(i = 0; fread(&length, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, input_file) != 0; i++)
            {
                length_multiplier++;
                indexs = realloc(indexs, sizeof(index_t *) * length_multiplier);
                indexs[i] = malloc(sizeof(index_t));
        
                indexs[i]->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * length + 1);
                fread(indexs[i]->name, sizeof(char), length, input_file);
                indexs[i]->name[length] = 0;
                fread(&indexs[i]->offset, sizeof(long), 1, input_file);
            }
            for(i = 0; i < length_multiplier; i++)
            {
                printf("%s\n", indexs[i]->name);
            }
            printf("Searching for: %s\n", input);
            
            pItem = (char*) bsearch(&input, indexs, length_multiplier, sizeof(indexs), cmpname);
    
            if(pItem == NULL)
            {
                printf("%s not found\n", pItem);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("found %s\n", pItem);
            }
    
            //FREEING MEMORY
            for(int i = 0; i < length_multiplier; i++)
            {
                free(indexs[i]->name);
                free(indexs[i]);
            }
            free(indexs);
            free(input);
    
            //fread(card[0]->id, sizeof(u_int32_t), 1, input_file);
            fclose(input_file);
    
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Exiting...\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "./parser: cannot open(%s%s%s): No such file or directory", "\"", argv[1], "\"");
        return 1;
    }
        
}
```

Here is my declared struct:

```
typedef struct index {
    char *name;
    long offset;
} index_t;
```

Answer (score 1):

The comparator function should compare two of whatever is in the array, not two different things. In your case, you want to compare two `index_t *`, not an `index_t *` and a `char *`. So it might look like this:

```
int cmpname (const void *pa, const void *pb) {
    const index_t * const *p1 = pa;
    const index_t * const *p2 = pb;
    //printf("Comparing: %s %s\n", p1, (char*)*p2);
        return strcmp((*p1)->name, (*p2)->name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `indexs` is declared like

```
index_t **indexs = NULL;
```

and points to the first element of an array with the element type `index_t *`.

```
indexs = realloc(indexs, sizeof(index_t *) * length_multiplier);
```

So in the call of `bsearch`

```
pItem = (char*) bsearch(&input, indexs, length_multiplier, sizeof(indexs), cmpname);
```

the object that accepts the result shall have the type `index_t **` because the function returns a pointer to the target element.

So the variable `pItem` shall be declared like

```
index_t **pItem;
```

And as the element of the array has the type `index_t *` then you have to use the argument `sizeof( index_t * )` instead of `sizeof( indexs )`.

On the other hand, the first parameter also shall be a pointer to an object of the type `index_t *`.

So before calling the function you could write for example

```
index_t input_item = { .name = input, .offset = 0 };
index_t *p_input_item = &input_item;
```

And the call of `bsearch` will look like

```
pItem = bsearch( &p_input_item, indexs, length_multiplier, sizeof( index_t * ), cmpname );
```

And then you could write

```
        if(pItem == NULL)
        {
            printf("%s not found\n", input);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("found %s\n", input);
        }
```

At last the comparison function can look like

```
int cmpname (const void *pa, const void *pb) {
    const index_t * const *p1 = pa;
    const index_t * const *p2 = pb;

    return strcmp( ( *p1 )->name, (*p2)->name );
}
```

Comment: Re: *"The first parameter also shall be a pointer to an object of the type index_t *"* ---> Is that required by the standard or is it because OP's comparison function was written as such?

Comment: @Haris From the description of bsearch "2 The bsearch function searches an array of nmemb objects, the initial element of which
is pointed to by base, for an element that matches the object pointed to by key. The
size of each element of the array is specified by size."